# How to re-export an individual lodash module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to re-export an individual lodash module in a TypeScript application as follows:

```
npm i lodash
npm i @types/lodash
```

```
export {default as debounce} from 'lodash/debounce';
```

When trying to compile with tsc the following error is shown:

> Module '".../node_modules/@types/lodash/debounce"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

and I cannot seem to understand what it means?

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

**tslint.json:**

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended",
        "tslint-react"
    ],
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
            "doc/**",
            "interfaces.flow/**",
            "node_modules/**",
            "rollout/**",
            "temp/**",
            "vendor/**"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "array-type": false,
        "arrow-parens": false,
        "ban-types": false,
        "comment-format": false,
        "forin": false,
        "indent": [true, "tabs"],
        "interface-name" : false,
        "interface-over-type-literal": false,
        "jsdoc-format": false,
        "jsx-no-multiline-js": false,
        "max-classes-per-file": false,
        "max-line-length": [true, 500],
        "member-access": false,
        "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
        "no-console": false,
        "no-empty": false,
        "no-shadowed-variable": [
            true,
            {
                "temporalDeadZone": false
            }
        ],
        "no-string-literal": false,
        "member-ordering": false,
        "object-literal-key-quotes": false,
        "object-literal-shorthand": false,
        "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
        "one-variable-per-declaration": false,
        "only-arrow-functions": false,
        "ordered-imports": false,
        "prefer-for-of": false,
        "quotemark": [true, "single", "jsx-double", "avoid-escape", "avoid-template"],
        "semicolon": [true, "always"],
        "space-before-function-paren": {
            "options": {
                "anonymous": "always",
                "asyncArrow": "always",
                "constructor": "never",
                "method": "never",
                "named": "never"
            }
        },
        "trailing-comma": [
            true,
            {
                "esSpecCompliant": true
            }
        ],
        "variable-name": {
            "options": ["ban-keywords", "check-format", "allow-pascal-case", "allow-leading-underscore"]
        }
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at lodash's debounce [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/afab656cfea0fab7899847e5b087532cc1ba6cb3/debounce.js#L212), the last line is:

```
export default debounce
```

This means that the function `debounce` is the default export of the `debounce.js` A default export has no name, so it can be renamed as any valid JavaScript name when importing.

To import the default export of the debounce file, do not use curly braces. Then export it on a separate line:

```
import debounce = require('lodash/debounce');

export { debounce };
```

or re-export the named function from the library:

```
export { debounce } from 'lodash';
```

Comment: Using `export debounce from 'lodash/debounce';` generates multiple errors: `Declaration or statement expected.`, `Cannot find name 'debounce'.`, `';' expected.`, `Cannot find name 'from'.` and `';' expected.`. Using `export { debounce } from 'lodash';` does work but as I mentioned, I only want to use individual lodash modules.

Comment: Please also note, that `export {default as...}` is actually allowed according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: I've updated my answer. You may want to add your `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json` to the original question if you are working with them. And what do you mean "individual lodash modules? Are you aware of this https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce let me know if you still need help

Comment: I've added `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json`. With individual modules I mean importing `lodash/debounce` instead of `lodash`. I still don't know how to re-export a module except importing and exporting separately. The syntax I used with babel `export {default as debounce} from 'lodash/debounce';` does nork as expected and gives me the error message `Module '".../node_modules/@types/lodash/debounce"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`. It seems to be related to the types and not the imp0ort itself according to thze error message.